# Iterate a tuple with dict inside

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4

Having trouble iterating over tuples such as this:

```
t = ('a','b',{'c':'d'})

for a,b,c in t:
    print(a,b,c) # ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)

for a,b,*c in t:
    print(a,b,c) # ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

for a,b,**c in t:
    print (a,b,c) # Syntax error (can't do **c)
```

Anyone know how I can preserve the dictionary value? I would like to see `a='a', b='b', and c={'c':'d'}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to put `t` inside some other iterable container:

```
for a, b, c in [t]:
    print(a, b, c)
```

The problem with your attempts is that each on is iterating over a single element from `t` and trying to unpack that.  e.g. the first turn of the loop is trying to unpack `'a'` into three places (`a`, `b` and `c`).

---

Obviously, it's also probably better to just unpack directly (no loop required):

```
a, b, c = t
print(a, b, c)
```

Comment: Great! Thanks, putting it inside a list works as I was expecting.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you iterating at all when it's a single `tuple`? Just unpack the single `tuple`, if that's what you need to do:

```
a, b, c = t
print(a, b, c)
```

Or if it's just printing you want to do unpack in the call itself:

```
print(*t)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for a,b,c in [t]:
    print(a,b,c)
```

Putting `t` inside a list will allow you to unpack it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
for x in t:
    print(x)
```

`x` will take all the values in `t` iteratively, so `'a'`, then `'b'` and finally `{'c':'d'}`.

And to print exactly `a = 'a'` etc you can do:

```
for param, val in zip(["a","b","c"], t):
    print(param,"=",val)
```

Comment: Doing it this way produces only one item in the tuple per iteration, and is not quite what I was looking for. Thanks for the quick response though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tuple unpacking with multiple assignment:

```
a, b, c = t
print(a, b, c)
```